# TextView displays same text while getting Intent from a different activity

Tags: android

I am having problems with retrieving Intents from a different activity. So what I want the app to do is after the user checks the checkbox and click a button. A `textView` in a different activity will display a certain text.
T am getting the `textView` to display text it is just that it is displaying the same text no matter which `checkBox` is clicked.

Here is the first Activity:

```
public static final String systemDisplay1 = "checkBoxA";
public String valuetoPass1 = "";
public static final String systemDisplay2 = "checkBoxB";
String valuetoPass2 = ""; 
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent start = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, 
Main4Activity.class);
            start.putExtra(systemDisplay1, 
valuetoPass1);
            start.putExtra(systemDisplay2, 
valuetoPass2);
            startActivity(start);
        }
    });

 radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            RadioButton checkBoxA = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);
            if (null != checkBoxA) {
            valuetoPass1= "";
            } else {
                valuetoPass = "Business";
            }
            RadioButton checkBoxB = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);
            if (checkBoxB != null) {
                valuetoPass2 = "";
            }else {
                valuetoPass2 = "Education";
            }

        }
    });
}
```

And here is the next Activity

```
 TextView systemView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.systemView);

 Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent.getStringExtra(systemdisplay1)!= null){
     systemView.setText("");
    }else {
        systemView.setText("Business");
    }


        Intent intent1 = getIntent();
        if (intent1.getStringExtra(systemDisplay2)!= null){
            systemView.setText("");
        }else{
            systemView.setText("Education");
        }
    }
}
```

No matter which `checkBox` I click the `TextView` will show "Education". What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm guessing your second if doesn't find any extra (say you're passing the first instead) so it defaults to the else branch, which sets "Education" (overwriting the setting of the first text) like you're asking the code to do. Please think what you should do instead, is super simple.

Comment: what are you sending to next activity ? share the code

Comment: valuetoPass2  is initialized to "Education" and is only ever set to "Education" so that's all your current code will ever display... It's not clear enough what you're trying to do though to really suggest a fix. Your check boxes as coded have no effect. Maybe you should only have one value to pass?

Comment: @Alessio sorry I kind of get the problem now, but I don't know how to solve it. What should I do?

Comment: @Mira is so simple, that you should really think about it. Think what you're trying to accomplish: upon selection, you want to show such selected text. So do it: let the activity which owns the selection to pass via the intent the selected text, and let the intent receiver to look into the intent's bundle: if string is meaningful (not null, not empty), set the text. That's all. :)

Comment: also @Mira try this: spit the problem into smaller steps, and debug (using something like _Log.d("mira", "my value is: " + myValue)_ ) the values at each step; this way you'll make sure that each step makes exactly what you want to have

Comment: @Alessio I changed the code trying to keep in mind what you wrote, but it still I still have the same problem. Can you tell me where the problem is and how I can solve it because I am actually clueless right now.

Comment: @Mira then please show us the code, and show us the debugging lines you obtain at which point. Don't paste all the code, only the relevant parts

Comment: @Alessio I updated the code in my question and as for the debugging lines, I don't see anything weird or stuff that can help solve the problem.

Comment: @Mira show us the debug lines you get, and at which point

Comment: @Alessio actually it's okay I think I might have figured out something that will solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

In my understanding, you want to send one specific selection to another activity. So, it will be better if you, use the radio buttons instead of checkboxes.

```
public static final String systemDisplay1 = "selection";
public String valuetoPass1 = "Business";
```

Change valuetoPass1 according to a radio button selection by the user. And pass this string to another activity using intent. Get string extra from the intent and set it to the TextView.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you want to allow multiple selection, e.g. To allow the selection of education and business. If that's the case:
Use three boolean variables to store each decision and put those on the intent.
If you only want to allow one selection:
Change the checkboxes to a radio group with radio buttons and use just one String to store the selection.

Answer (score 0):

The Preferred approach:

Try changing the checkboxes to Radio buttons and form a RadioGroup.

Code:

```
public static final String systemDisplay1 = "checkBoxA";
public String valuetoPass1 = "Business";
public static final String systemDisplay2 = "checkBoxB";
String valuetoPass2 = "Education"; 
String intentParam = null; // set default value
final static String KEY = "paramKey";
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent start = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, 
Main4Activity.class);
            start.putExtra(KEY,intentParam);
            startActivity(start);
        }
    });

RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) 
        {
        RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);
        if (null != radioButton) 
            {
                intentParam = ""// set the value depending on the type of radio button the user has checked.
            }

    }
});
```

}

Receiving Activity

```
TextView systemView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.systemView);
    if (this.getIntent().getStringExtra(Main2Activity.KEY)!= null)
    {
        systemView.setText(this.getIntent().getStringExtra(Main2Activity.KEY);
    } 
    else 
    {
        systemView.setText(" Set any default value");
    }
```

Comment: I tried this code, but I still have the same problem. Like if I click the first radio button it will show me the text the is suppose to be displayed if I clicked the second radio button.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you must not declare the data at the top

```
public static final String systemDisplay1 = "checkBoxA";
public String valuetoPass1 = "";
public static final String systemDisplay2 = "checkBoxB";
String valuetoPass2 = "";
String valuetoPass3 = ""; 
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent start = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, 
Main4Activity.class);
            start.putExtra(systemDisplay1, 
valuetoPass1);
            start.putExtra(systemDisplay2, 
valuetoPass2);
            startActivity(start);
        }
    });

checkBoxA.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton 
compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if (checkBoxA.isChecked()) {
                valuetoPass1 = "Business";
            }
        }
    });
checkBoxB.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton 
compoundButton, boolean b) {
    if (checkBoxB.isChecked()){
        valuetoPass2 = "Education";
    }
}
});
checkBoxC.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton 
compoundButton, boolean b) {
    if (checkBoxC.isChecked()){
        valuetoPass3 = "Engineering";
    }
}
});
}
```